# Require/import statements don't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, require

I'm having trouble loading the semantic-ui-calendar npm module into my application.

I've successfully loaded it into my HTML using a script tag,

but every time I try to load it into my applications I get errors.

In a standard HTML/JS/CSS application,

I've tried loading it into my index.js like so

```
var Semantic = require('semantic-ui-calendar');


$(function() {


  $('#example1')Semantic.calendar();

});
```

And I always get this error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

I've tried placing the require statement inside the "document ready" function as well, but to no avail.

I'm a little confused about whether or not I can assign an arbitrary variable value to the module.

The [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/semantic-ui-calendar) doesn't specify a namespace so I just went with Semantic as my variable name. Am I missing something here?

The other thing I suspect is that because this package uses Bower and Gulp (two things I really don't know anything about), perhaps there's a different protocol for requiring this package in the browser?

Can someone point me in the right direction. Please and thank you!

Comment: `$('#example1')Semantic.calendar();` doesn't look right. What are you trying to do?

Comment: In my html, I have a div
    <h3>Input</h3> 
      <div class="ui calendar" id="example1"> 
         <div class="ui input left icon"> 
           <i class="calendar icon"></i>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Date/Time"> 
          </div> 
       </div> 
When I included semantic-calendar-ui as a link, calling $('#example1')calendar(); in my js file worked perfectly. But now, since I want to use semantic-calendar-ui as an NPM package, my reasoning was that I need to assign the library to an arbirtrary value "Semantic" and I'm pulling the .calendar() method off the library.

Comment: require() won't work in browser out of the box, are you using requirejs or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `require` is not actually part of vanilla js as browsers implement it. Bower/gulp adds it in a way that browsers can support, but it also adds an extra step where you code has to be built for the browser.

In order to use `require`, you need to use a build tool that adds it, and do the extra build step on your source.

http://andy-carter.com/blog/a-beginners-guide-to-package-manager-bower-and-using-gulp-to-manage-components

Comment: @sheriffderek Thanks! I skimmed the question a little too fast. Answer updated.

Comment: I didn't catch their setup either. : )

Comment: I'm pretty sure the method is also not being called correctly.

Comment: @sheriffderek, does it have something to do with the way I'm assigning the library to the var Semantic?

Comment: Yeah, I think the call can still just be `$('#example1').calendar();`

Comment: @SeanyboyLee `$('#example1')Semantic.calendar();` is bad js syntax. According to the docs for that library, you don't need to namespace it after you've required it. You should just be able to do this: `$('#example1').calendar();` assuming the docs are right.